# json_encode for use in Google Maps

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-maps

I am having  a problem with outputting data in JSON format for use in Google maps. I need the JSON in this format:

```
  {"title":"Park Ave Penthouse", "location": {"lat": 40.7713024, "lng": -73.9632393}},
  {"title":"Chelsea", "location": {"lat": 40.7347062, "lng": -73.9895759}}
```

I can't figure out how to output this part: `"location": {"lat": 40.7713024, "lng": -73.9632393}`. I have the following code but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 $arr = array();

 for ($i=0; $i <$numrows; $i++) {
    $stmt->fetch();

   $arr[] = array(
     "title" => strval($title),
     "locations: {lat => $lat, lng => $lng"
    );
 } 
 header("Content-Type", "application/json");
 echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: What language is this?  This looks like a string to me: `"locations: {lat => $lat, lng => $lng"`, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like PHP and the following line looks really weird:

```
 "locations: {lat => $lat, lng => $lng"
```

To get the required format, you can use an associative array:

```
…
$arr[] = array(
  "title" => strval($title),
  "locations" => array(
    "lat" => $lat,
    "lng" => $lng
  )
);
…
```